# Tautological ring for moduli of flat connections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, characteristic-classes, chern-classes

Let $X$ be a smooth complex manifold and $G$ a connected complex algebraic group. Let $M$ denote the moduli stack of flat $G$-connections on $X$. Over $M\times X$, we have the tautological $G$-bundle, denoted by $E$. We can think of this as a map $M\times X\rightarrow BG$. Thus, for every $c\in H^*(BG)$, we have, by pullback, the universal class
$$
c(E)\in H^*(M\times X)=H^*(M)\otimes H^*(X).
$$
(We use rational cohomology everywhere.)

It follows that given $\gamma \in H^*(X)$, we obtain a class $c_\gamma(E) \in H^*(M)$. These are known as the tautological classes.

Question: For which pairs $(X,G)$ do the tautological classes generate $H^*(M)$?

For instance, if $X$ is a smooth complex algebraic curve and $G=GL_r$, then [Markman](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0009109) showed that tautological classes generate $H^*(M)$.

Comment: If I understand correctly your use of "flat connection", it depends only on the fundamental group of $M$.  But most manifolds $M$ are not Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.  So why should the cohomology of $M$ faithfully encode the cohomology of the Eilenberg-MacLane space with that same fundamental group?